# При создании поста получить ID и название рубрики

Tags: php, laravel

Есть пользователь, с возможностью создать собственные уникальные рубрики для публикации в них записей.
Не выходит реализовать следующее.

Пользователь переходит в общий список своих рубрик, где у каждой рубрики есть кнопка "Создать запись". Нужно получить ID этой самой рубрики на странице создания поста.

Модели и таблицы связаны между собой(один ко всем), в массиве все эти данные существуют, но, не удаётся присвоить ID конкретной рубрики, внутри которой совершен клик. Соответственно у пользователя всё так же остается выпадающий список его рубрик, вместо одной нужной.

К примеру, если записать в роут кнопки "Создать запись" - **route('user.post.create', ['rubric' -> $rubrics->id])**,то в URL передаётся ID этой самой рубрики. А вот как получить этот ID внутри формы, не могу найти решения. Подскажите в каком направлении плыть, или может есть простое решение? В гугле ответов не нашел, так как это не совсем стандартный вопрос по laravel, затрудняюсь даже правильно сформулировать.

**Контроллер записей**

```
    public function create() {
    $users = Auth::user()->id;
    $rubrics = Rubric::where('user_id', '=', $users)->get(); //здесь я получаю список всех рубрик этого юзера.

    return view('user.post.create', compact('rubrics'));
}
```

**Модель записей**

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Stem\LinguaStemRu;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Iatstuti\Database\Support\CascadeSoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model {

protected $fillable = [
    'category_id',
    'user_id',
    'rubric_id',
    'name',
    'slug',
    'content',
    'image',
];

public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function rubric() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Rubric::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант, это использовать хелпер `request()` во вьюхе:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rubricId" value="{{ request()->get('rubricId') }}">
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request